# how to reconstruct image given feature vector from VGG19?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, vgg-net, imagenet

i am using the VGG19 deep CNN to get the output of the block5 pooling layer in VGG19, based on some input image. i will use these features as target vector for another machine learning algorithm.

does anyone know how to reconstruct the original image based on the features from block5 (or any other layer)?

right now my code looks like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block5_pool').output)

img_path = 'C:/shared/a5/images/training/n01518878_8432.JPEG'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

features = model.predict(x)
```

i would like to take these features, and get back the original image. does anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Comment: I am also looking for the answer for this question. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: The image reconstruction using L-BFGS is implemented in our library, icnn (https://github.com/KamitaniLab/icnn).
To switch the reconstruction algorithm, modify importing part of a "reconstruct_image" function in sample code of DeepImageReconstruction (https://github.com/KamitaniLab/DeepImageReconstruction), like

from icnn.icnn_lbfgs import reconstruct_image  # for L-BFSG without DGN

or

from icnn.icnn_dgn_lbfgs.py import reconstruct_image # for L-BFSG with DGN

Comment: okay..I will check it...thank you so much!